# Send messages to NodeWithName@"name"

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode

i have created a custom SpriteNode class with some public methods.
In the main scene of my project i added multiple objects of that class - each with a different node name:

```
obj.name = @"name1";
```

Later in the project i want to send messages to specific objects, calculated by their names. I tried:

```
[[self childNodeWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"name%i", counter]] customMethod];
```

But that does not worked..

Comment: assert that `[self childNodeWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"name%i", counter]` does return the correct object

Comment: You'll need to cast the returned value of `childNodeWithName` (an `SKNode *`) to a `MyCustomClass` pointer to call any of the custom methods.

Comment: can you post an example?

Comment: Try this `[(MyCustomClass *)[self childNodeWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"name%i", counter]] customMethod];`

Comment: This works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to add your desired nodes to an array and loop through as required to find the specific node you want.

```
for(SKSpriteNode *object in self.myArray) {

    if([object.name isEqualToString:@"name1"]) {
        [object methodName];
    }
}
```